# Combining fluent and object initializer syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using the .NET client NEST, is it possible to combine the two syntaxes like below where the Query is written in one syntax and the Aggregation in another?

```
var request = new SearchRequest();
request.Query = new MatchAllQuery();
request.Aggregations = new AggregationContainerDescriptor<Car>().Terms("color", x => x.Field(doc => doc.Color));
_elasticClient.Search<Car>(request);
```

The compile error here being that a `AggregationContainerDescriptor` is not assailable to a `AggregationDictionary`

Comment: Both `*Descriptor` and object initializer types implement common interfaces, so you should be able to mix and match any of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your descriptor to `IAggregationContainer` and get `Aggregations` from there:

```
var request = new SearchRequest();
request.Query = new MatchAllQuery();
var aggregationContainer = (IAggregationContainer)new AggregationContainerDescriptor<Car>().Terms("color", x => x.Field(doc => doc.Color));
request.Aggregations = aggregationContainer.Aggregations;
var searchResponse = _elasticClient.Search<Car>(request);
```

Hope that helps.